# Is there a sane way to parse a nested JSON with unknown structure into an object or a dictionary in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift5

Disclaimer: There are quite a few similar questions posted, but not one of them seems to duplicate my own

Suppose my app receives a JSON from quite poorly engineered API, and that JSON that looks something like this:

```
{
    "matches": {
        "page1": [{
            "name": "John",
            "surname": "Doe",
            "interests": [{
                    "id": 13,
                    "text": "basketball"
                },
                {
                    "id": 37,
                    "text": "competitive knitting"
                },
                {
                    "id": 127,
                    "text": "romcoms"
                }
            ]
        }],
        "page2": [{
            "name": "Dwayne",
            "surname": "Johnson",
            "interests": [{
                    "id": 42,
                    "text": "sci-fi"
                },
                {
                    "id": 255,
                    "text": "round numbers"
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
}
```

If I want to get, say, all the interests from all the matches, in native Swift functionality I'd first have to do some like this:

```
struct MatchesData: Codable {
    let matches: Matches
}

struct Matches: Codable {
    let page1: Page1
    let page2: Page2
}

struct Page1: Codable {
    let interests: [Interest]
}

struct Page2: Codable {
    let interests: [Interest]
}

struct Interest: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let text: String
}
```

Then, I'd have to use the structs I created, in a manner like this:

```
func handleJSON(_ response: Data) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(MatchesData.self, from: response)
            // Only here I can start actually working with the data API sent me, it's in decodedData
            ...
        } catch {
            // Handle the errors somehow
            return
        }
}
```

While this *kinda* works, it has two major drawbacks.

Firstly, that all put together is an insane amount of preparation and code in general for a task that simple, and it doesn't comply with the DRY principle.

Lastly, this approach simply doesn't work if you don't know the exact structure of the JSON beforehand. For instance, in my example, what if the amount of pages wasn't fixed to 2, but could rather be anywhere between, say, 1 and 50?

In other languages that have sane in-built tools for working with JSON, I'd just parse the JSON and recursively iterate through matches to do what I need with the content.

**Examples** (without safety precautions to improve readability)**:**

JS:

```
const handleJSON = jsonStr => {
  const jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr)
  const matches = jsonObj.matches
  Object.values(matches).forEach(page => {
    // Recursively process every page to find what I need and process it
  })
}
```

Python 3:

```
import json

def handleJSON(jsonStr):
  jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)
  matches = jsonObj['matches']
  for page in matches:
    # Recursively process every page to find what I need and process it
```

PHP:

```
function handleJSON($jsonStr) {
    $jsonObj = json_decode($jsonStr);
    $matches = $jsonObj->matches;
    foreach ($matches as $page) {
        // Recursively process every page to find what I need and process it
    }
}
```

So, the question is, how do I achieve the same in Swift in a sane manner, just like in the examples above (which definitely means roughly the same amount of code)? If you know a 3rd party lib that does just that, I'd happily accept such a lib for an answer.

**UPDATE:** Just found out about [Jsonify](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Jsonify), which seems to be at least as good of a solution to my issues as SwiftyJSON, maybe even better. One should probably try both out for a while to decide which one suits their taste and needs better

Comment: `Codable` is designed to encourage people to stay away from "poorly engineered APIs" :-)

Comment: In your `MatchesData` structure, what about having a Dictionary instead of a structure `Matches` with two fields? `[String: Interest]`

Comment: @SimonMoshenko that'd be better, but I couldn't really figure out how to skip the intermediate structures though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an external library that does this, you can try [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON), which allows you to get all the interests like this:

```
    let json = JSON(parseJSON: jsonString)
    let matchesObject = json["matches"]
    // I assume the total number of pages is stored in numberOfPages
    let interests = (0..<2).flatMap {
        matchesObject["page\($0 + 1)"].arrayValue.flatMap {
            $0["interests"].arrayValue.map {
                // using the same Interest struct as in your question
                Interest(id: $0["id"].intValue, text: $0["text"].stringValue)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yup, SwiftyJSON seems about what I need, greatly appreciated! I need to learn more about mapping in Swift and practice a little more with closures. But what I see in SwiftyJSON's documentation is more or less the thing I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

First of all, keep in mind that there is no need for structs to be global in scope. You can define a struct "temporarily" within a function just for the purposes of helping you dip down into the JSON and fetch out a value. Thus the overall architecture of the code is in no way marred.

Second, your own example JSON is not as insane as you suggest; what's insane is your own structs. First, your use of two identical structs. There is no purpose whatever to having a struct Page1 and a struct Page2. Second, there is no purpose to your Matches either. That isn't what your JSON is. In your MatchesData, the `matches` property should be merely a dictionary of type `[String:[Person]]` (you don't have a Person type but that is what these things seem to be).

If your claim is that the dictionary *should* have been an array in the JSON, fine, I agree. If the keys are always going to be named `"page1"`, `"page2"`, etc., the JSON is silly in that respect. But then you can *later* transform the `[String:[Person]]` into an array of Person ordered by the numbers on the end of the String `"page"` keys. And then you can map that into an array of Interest if you want to throw away the rest of the Person info.

In other words: How you *parse* the data that arrives to you and how you *maintain* the data you are interested in, are two completely different matters. Parse the data just get yourself out of the JSON world and into the object world; then transform it into a form that is useful to you, keeping what you need and ignoring what you don't.

Here's an example of the sort of thing you might do:

```
let data = s.data(using: .utf8)!

struct Result : Codable {
    let matches:[String:[Person]]
}
struct Person : Codable {
    let name:String
    let surname:String
    let interests:[Interests]
}
struct Interests : Codable {
    let id:Int
    let text:String
}
let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data)
```

Okay, so now we've parsed the darned data. But we hate its structure. So change it!

```
// okay, but dictionary is silly: flatten to an array
let persons1 = Array(result.matches)
func pageNameToNumber(_ s:String) -> Int {
    let num = s.dropFirst(4)
    return Int(num)!
}
let persons2 = persons1.map {(key:pageNameToNumber($0.key), value:$0.value)}
let persons3 = persons2.sorted {$0.key < $1.key}
let persons4 = persons3.map { $0.value }
```

But we still have the silly one-element arrays to deal with:

```
// okay, but the one-element array is silly, so flatten that too
let persons5 = persons4.map {$0.first!}
```

And now you say you never cared about the person stuff at all, all you want is the list of interests:

```
// okay but all I care about are the interests
let interests = persons5.map {$0.interests}
```

(And then you could flatten the interests as well, or whatever.)

Now, if all of that were done in a method, then only the Interests struct would need to be public; everything else is just a tool to get the values extracted, and can be private to the interior of the method. Only make public the structs that your app really needs / wants for the maintenance of the data. The overall lesson, though, is: just parse the darned JSON into objects: now you are in the Swift object world, and can re-parse those objects in whatever way is ultimately useful to you.

Comment: I think one of the things you are trying to say is that OP should not only focus on a "simple task" such as "getting all the interests", and that they should parse _all_ the data first (who knows when they will come in handy?) and then flat map to all the interests. And if they do this, then this amount of "preparation" would not seem "too much". Did I interpret your answer correctly?

Comment: That's a great suggestion, I appreciate it! I'll dive deeper into that, cause I am yet to figure out how to separate the two concerns in Swift. Anyways, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, and I've expanded my answer to illustrate that with code, but in fact I never say it so clearly as you do in your comment!

Comment: @matt once again, thanks! See, fetching the interests is just an example of a task I could want to achieve, that's why I didn't even write implementation for it. As for the silly one-element arrays, I meant that there can be more people per page than one, and the array wouldn't be single-element in real life. I just didn't want to make an already long post even longer by further populating the JSON. Apparently, that caused an ambiguity.

Comment: That's fine, and doesn't mar the discussion in any way. Your example was only an example, and so is mine. I'm just showing you how to _think_ about the problem so that you feel better about the JSON at the one end and your ultimate mined data at the other end. You can modify my particular transformations in any way you like! They are just hypothetical responses.

Comment: Also, the JSON itself is from an old project in a different language, I just took it because it was a good sample of a nested JSON with an unpredictable structure, thus, requiring recursive processing. Also, the entire point of my question was how to avoid any preparation at all (like in the examples). Apparently SwiftyJSON is what allows exactly that, and that's why I selected the other answer as the correct one. Nevertheless, I greatly appreciate the effort you've put into this one. It gave me new knowledge, just not the one I asked for, and I can and will use it in the future. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, and if you don't want to rely on a third party library, you could do the same thing with JSONSerialization. But rarely do we know _so_ little about the incoming JSON as to need to do that; I can't agree with the accepted answer, unless your JSON is downright random.

Comment: @matt now that's all about priorities now. When I want to rely as little as possible on anything, I write stuff in ANSI C, and keep it as low-level as possible. Then I only have to rely on things that proved their reliability through being tested for almost 40 years now. When I write in Swift, my top priority is to minimize PITA in the process. Anyways, discussion of priorities doesn't contribute to StackOverflow as a base of knowledge, so we should probably understand each other by now and either split our ways or continue the discussion in private messages